# AWS S3 filename

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I’m trying to build application with backend in java that allows users to create a text with images in it (something like a a personal blog). I’m planning to store these images to s3 bucket. When uploading image files to bucket i’m hashing the original name and store the hashed one in the bucket. Images are for display purpose only, no user will be able to download them. Frontend displays these images by getting a path to them from the server. So the question is, is there any need to store original name of the image file in the database? And what are the reasons, if any, of doing so?

Comment: Sorry, but your question does not have enough detail for us to understand what you are asking. Please Edit your question and provide more details, for example: What are you hashing and why? How are these S3 object going to be used? How are the files being uploaded?

Answer (score 0):

I guess in general it is not needed because what is more important is how these resources are used or managed in the system.

Assuming your service is something like data access (similar to google drive), I don't think it's necessary to store it in DB, unless you want to make faster search queries.